# How to display user Controls on windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, user-controls

We have installed .Net  Web Application in Windows 2003 R2. when trying to browse the website from Windows 8 operating system User controls are not loaded.Is there any command to show web site with User controls.
for other Operating systems we have run the Caspol command then user controls loaded successfully.Tried same in Windows 8 but no use.

Comment: There's nothing special about Windows 8 in this regard. It's more likely a specific of your IIS/.NET/ASP configuration. Are you seeing any error messages? Is .NET installed and registered with IIS on the machine? What's the content of your site (which .NET version, WebForms vs MVC, etc)?

Comment: we used Caspol command to show User controls in other OS.but Caspol command doesnt helped us for Windows 8

Comment: What version of .NET is your application? The [Caspol docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz.aspx) give a bunch of disclaimers about this not working post .NET4, and having separate 32/64-bit versions - as a starting point. Have you tried that stuff?

Comment: This is a .net framework 3.5 Application.We have deployed in a 32 bit machine.When we try to access from another machine(Windows 8)  User controls are not displaying

Comment: Have you installed .NET 3.5? In Windows 8, only .NET 4 is installed by default; it's possible that the app is running under .NET 4 and so your Caspol changes are being ignored.  Do you see any error messages? If user controls aren't displaying I'd assume there's an error somewhere that would explain why in more detail...

Comment: No we have installed in Other machine with framework 3.5 .When we try to browse from Client having windows 8 OS its not working

Comment: .... so what you're saying is that your *client* machine is Windows 8? What is the server machine? Do other clients using the same server see the custom controls?

Comment: This may be the "browser downgrade" problem. Make sure your install Windows updates (the .NET updates specifically) on the server machine.

Comment: Server version is Windows2003 R2,Every thing works well when we are browsing from other Operating systems but not on Windows 8..

Comment: Maybe you mean that your HTML is not compatible with IE10?

Comment: Is there any solution for that .?   I cann't say that it is not compatible to the Customer

Comment: Are you loading .NET user controls in the HTML in the browser? I know this used to be possible, even tried it once 10 years ago. You shouldn't be doing this for lot's of reasons. And I wouldn't be surprised that it indeed does not work in IE10, certainly not the "modern" IE10 (i.e. the fullscreen one).

Comment: unfortunately its not working :(

Comment: Maybe you should show us the HTML that is "not working".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37989/discussion-between-rakesh-and-kris-vandermotten)

Comment: Some thing is blocking in IE10,windows 8 to download ,I have tried with various settings in Internet options but of no use..